# How to fix this traceback error with this addon?

Tags: python, add-on, bezier-curves, error

I'm trying to use this addon: [https://github.com/ucupumar/bevel-curve-tools/blob/master/**init**.py](https://github.com/ucupumar/bevel-curve-tools/blob/master/__init__.py) in blender 2.82 but when I'm creating a new beveled curve I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Saynom\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.82\scripts\addons\bevel-curve-tools-master\__init__.py", line 539, in execute
    subsurf = self.subsurf)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\2.82\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 201, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.curve.y_add_bevel_to_curve.poll() failed, context is incorrect

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

I don't understand Python but is there any quick fix to this issue by any chance?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Were you in edit or object mode when you used the function of this add-on that caused this error ? Maybe try in the other one

Comment: @Gorgious When you add a new beveled curve in object mode it automatically puts you in edit mode. And if I'm already in edit mode I also get this error.

Comment: Alright, that was my 2 cents ! Then I don't know. I saw you already created an issue on the github page, I think you should wait for the author to get back to you, it is hard to say otherwise. Good luck !

Comment: @Gorgious Alright, thanks!